# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] using {{myvideo[currentSlideIndex]?.title}}

Tags: angular, typescript

In ts code I have

`currentSlideIndex: number = 0;`

In html code I have

```
 <mat-carousel ... (change)="currentSlideIndex = $event ;toggleVideo1()">
        <mat-carousel-slide #matCarouselSlide *ngFor="let event of myvideo; let i = index"
                      overlayColor="#00000040" [hideOverlay]="true">
                              <video *ngIf="event?.Video" controls style="width: 100%;">
                              <source src="{{event?.Video}}" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
        </mat-carousel-slide>
           {{myvideo[currentSlideIndex]?.title}}
        </mat-carousel>
```

In carousel I have 3 slider, index 0, 1 ,2

In index 0 show error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
> at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your object is not loaded when starting the page, perhaps it is a request. So you need to protect with an IF statement: `{{myvideo != null ? myvideo[currentSlideIndex]?.title : ''}}`